# How to mutate dataclass argument upon instantiation?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a `dataclass` that looks like this:

```
@dataclass
class AllLastTick:
    tick_type_mapping = {
        0: "bid_size",
        1: "bid_price",
        2: "ask_price",
        3: "ask_size",
        4: "last_trade_price",
        5: "last_trade_size"
    }
    time: int
    tick_type: int
    price: float
    size: Decimal
```

And I instantiate it like this:

```
tick_data = (
    time,
    tick_type,
    price,
    size
)

tick = AllLastTick(*tick_data)
```

The result is something that looks like this:

```
AllLastTick(time=1699358716, tick_type=2, price=178.49, size=Decimal('200'))
```

What I'd like to do is convert the `tick_type` argument to the value in `AllLastTick .tick_type_mapping` when the class is instantiated.

The ideal result would look like this:

```
AllLastTick(time=1699358716, tick_type="ask_price", price=178.49, size=Decimal('200'))
```

I've tried using something like this:

```
...
tick_type: int = field(default_factory=lambda x: tick_type_mapping[x])
...
```

Which I understand does not work because the fields cannot be mutable (question mark on this point).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I can update `tick_type` to type `str`

Comment: Well if that's case I would suggest to update your question.

Comment: could you make `tick_type_mapping` a variable outside of the dataclass and then use that when instantiating `AllLastTick` ?

Comment: IMHO, this question conveys a very useful pattern that was not so far embraced by the language (dataclasses, argument passing or typing system alike), of accepting a wider range of types for one field, and coercing the value to a strict type. 
Anyone reading this: we could talk about a proposal for the core language itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `__post_init__`? See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing).

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from decimal import Decimal

class AllLastTick:
    tick_type_mapping = {
        0: "bid_size",
        1: "bid_price",
        2: "ask_price",
        3: "ask_size",
        4: "last_trade_price",
        5: "last_trade_size"
    }
    time: int
    tick_idx: int
    tick_type: str = field(init=False)
    price: float
    size: Decimal
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.tick_type = self.tick_type_mapping[self.tick_idx]
```

Then,

```
tick = AllLastTick(*tick_data)
```

Will use the index and define a tick type for you. You just need to store the key in another attribute (`tick_idx`).

Comment: Also: `tick_Type` could be a `@property` here, which would use `tick_idx`. However, `tick_ix` itself might not be desired upon serialization or otherwise reading the class fields.